# Where did Contacts.Groups.GROUP_MY_CONTACTS go?

Tags: android, contactscontract, android-contacts

I'm working on an app that deals with contacts, and I am looking for ContactsContract compatible equivalents to both of these constants:

```
Contacts.Groups.GROUP_MY_CONTACTS
Contacts.Groups.GROUP_ANDROID_STARRED
```

I find it hard to believe that these constants no longer apply in ContactsContract. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get GROUP_ANDROID_STARRED from the [STARRED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.ContactOptionsColumns.html#STARRED) column in ContactsContract.Contacts. I'm not too sure about the GROUP_MY_CONTACTS, but perhaps [IN_VISIBLE_GROUP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.ContactsColumns.html#IN_VISIBLE_GROUP) from ContactsContract.ContactsColumns may be what you're looking for.

Comment: @marc-bernstein Thanks for your answer. I haven't been able to get my code working using the GROUP_ANDROID_STARRED column. Do you have an example of code to pull this value for a contact?